# Does File() In asp.net mvc close the stream?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering if you do something like

```
public FileResult result()
{
   Stream stream = new Stream();
   return File(stream,"text/html","bob.html");
}
```

if File() would close the stream for you? Since I tried to put the "stream" in a using statement but it always gave me a error saying the stream was closed.

```
public FileResult result()
{
    using(Stream stream = new Stream())
    {
       return File(stream,"text/html","bob.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help. [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: When does it give you the error that the stream is closed?

Comment: When it hits return File(). It says the stream is closed.

Comment: As I understand it, error with `using` statement is based on the fact that returning `FileStreamResult` at the end of your method happens before reading from file. In other words, when the end of `using` is reached, there is only stream created - no data from file was read yet. Reading starts later, in deep of ASP.Net)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using the `File` object to send the resulting file for download as bob.html then yes.

I believe that all standard Streams (OutputStream, FileStream, CryptoStream) will attempt to flush when closed or disposed.

There are a number of classes within the MVC framework that implement the base `FileResult` class.

```
System.Web.Mvc.FileResult
System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult
System.Web.Mvc.FilePathResult
System.Web.Mvc.FileStreamResult
```

Comment: What other situations would you use File() other thank sending the file for download?