# Does FileStreamResult close Stream?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My question is similar to this question:
[Does File() In asp.net mvc close the stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129428/does-file-in-asp-net-mvc-close-the-stream)

I have the follows in C# MVC 4.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathToFileOnDisk, FileMode.Open);
FileStreamResult fsResult = new FileStreamResult(fs, "Text");
return fsResult;
```

Will `fs` be closed automatically by `FileStreamResult`? thanks!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Yes. It uses a `using` block around the stream, and that ensures that the resource will dispose.

Here is the internal [implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/FileStreamResult.cs) of the `FileStreamResult` WriteFile method:

```
protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
{
    // grab chunks of data and write to the output stream
    Stream outputStream = response.OutputStream;
    using (FileStream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

        while (true)
        {
            int bytesRead = FileStream.Read(buffer, 0, BufferSize);
            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                // no more data
                break;
            }

            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! just curious, where did you find it? Andrei linked to the code for MVC 3; yours looks like another version.

Comment: This is MVC5 latest version. I got the code with a decompiler, but you can find the actual code on codeplex, and it includes comments too ;)

Comment: In MVC6 (vNext) stream [is being closed too](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/25eb50120eceb62fd24ab5404210428fcdf0c400/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/FileStreamResult.cs)

Comment: Now moved [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/FileStreamResultExecutor.cs/#L33-L39).

Comment: Now moved to the `dotnet/aspnetcore` repository: [FileStreamResultExecutor.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v7.0.5/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/FileStreamResultExecutor.cs#L38)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 50 reputation to comment. I wanted to link to the implementation where the using statement is.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v8.0.2/src/Shared/ResultsHelpers/FileResultHelper.cs

```
internal static async Task WriteFileAsync(HttpContext context, Stream fileStream, RangeItemHeaderValue? range, long rangeLength)
{
    const int BufferSize = 64 * 1024;
    var outputStream = context.Response.Body;
    using (fileStream)
    {
        try
        {
            if (range == null)
            {
                await StreamCopyOperation.CopyToAsync(fileStream, outputStream, count: null, bufferSize: 64 * 1024, cancel: context.RequestAborted);
            }
            else
            {
                fileStream.Seek(range.From!.Value, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await StreamCopyOperation.CopyToAsync(fileStream, outputStream, rangeLength, BufferSize, context.RequestAborted);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Don't throw this exception, it's most likely caused by the client disconnecting.
            // However, if it was cancelled for any other reason we need to prevent empty responses.
            context.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```