# Why does ASP.NET MVC Controller FileStreamResult error on closed stream?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to return a csv file from an MVC Controller derived from a List.  I came up with the following code for controller based on combining what I read from docs and SO questions.  I must be missing something because I am getting yellow screen of death with "Cannot access a closed stream"...

```
public class ConsumersFileController : Controller
{
    private readonly TDCContext _db = new TDCContext();


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Consumer> list = _db.Consumers.ToList();

        //put List in memory stream object
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (memoryStream)
        {
            //return memory stream as file stream result:
            using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true))
            {
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    var itemBytes = item.Serialize();
                    binaryWriter.Write(itemBytes.Length);
                    binaryWriter.Write(itemBytes);

                }

                FileStreamResult fileStream =
                    new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "application/txt") {FileDownloadName = "zips.csv"};

                return fileStream;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
[ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.]
   System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed() +59
   System.IO.MemoryStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +14731549
   System.Web.Mvc.FileStreamResult.WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response) +93
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +831
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +607
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +134
```

How can the stream get closed if I am returning the result inside the `using` block of the stream?

Comment: Rewind stream before next reading. Like `memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)` or `memoryStream.Position=0`

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you don't understand? Possibly reading on how `using` work may actually answer why stream get closed... Obviously @Marko's suggestion not going to solve that...

Comment: To clarify what I don't understand, the memoryStream is being used inside a `using` block (which from my understanding from what I have read and experienced, means it will be closed and disposed of once the `using` block is done).  The fileStream (probably should have named it fileStreamResult) is returned INSIDE the memoryStream `using` block.  So, at what point is the memoryStream being closed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should remove:

```
using (memoryStream)
```

`FileStreamResult` will [dispose `memoryStream` for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275764/does-filestreamresult-close-stream).

*The reason that your code doesn't work is that the actual work that reads from `memoryStream` is not in your code - it is in MVC code that calls `fileStream.WriteFile`. But that code is executed somewhere higher up the call stack. And by the time `WriteFile` is called (which needs `memoryStream`) you have already disposed it.*

Comment: Removed the using block and BOOM!  That was it!  thank you so much!