# Unit test a stream which is returned in a using statement (and therefore closed)

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I'm trying to unit test an Azure function which returns a FileStreamResult like this:

```
using (var fileStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
{
    return new FileStreamResult(fileStream , "application/octet-stream")
        { FileDownloadName = "myfile.txt" };
}
```

The problem is as soon as my test attempts to check the contents of my stream (or any property on it), it can't because the stream has been released by the **using** statement. The 'response' var here is an HttpResponseMessage which contains a stream my tests mocked.

It feels very wrong to remove the using statement so that my tests can keep the stream alive whilst they read the return stream (this immediately makes the tests green). What's a good approach to this problem?

Comment: Surely this isn't just a problem with your tests? Anything which uses that method will see a `FileStreamResult` over a closed stream. Note that `FileStreamResult` will close the `fileStream` itself when it's finished -- you don't need to dispose it *as well* ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275764/does-filestreamresult-close-stream)), so it seems the *correct* approach is not to dispose `fileStream` yourself, but to let the `FileStreamResult` close it when it's finished with it.

Comment: Ah so FileStreamResult will take care of the close? No problem then!

Comment: [Yes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/FileStreamResultExecutor.cs#L31)