# Read large text file and stream response as JSON data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I need to read a 30 MB JSON file and stream the results as JSON data. I found the following code, but the code Serializes one large object, which creates a memory spike. How can I change the code to stream part of the data from the JSON text file and then stream the data back to the calling application as JSON?

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
{
     using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
     using (JsonTextWriter jtw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
     {
         JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
         ser.Serialize(jtw, hugeObject); //don't serialize the entire object. 
         //Read in some of the file and stream it back out until the entire text file is consumed. 
     }
 }, "application/json");
```

edit - hugeObject is an array of json data:

```
[
    {
        "agent": "name1",
        "entityCode": "010002",
        "state": "AL",
        "memberType": "U",
        "producerCode": "572714"
    },
    {
        "agent": "name2",
        "entityCode": "010002",
        "state": "AL",
        "memberType": "U",
        "producerCode": "572714"
    }
]
```

UPDATE - I have the following working, but the code creates one big string. I want to stream the data instead.

```
[HttpGet, Route("/api/GetAllData/{callingApp}")]
public IActionResult GetAllData(
 [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$"), Required, MaxLength(50)] string callingApp)
{
    string fileName = _config.GetSection("AllAgentsPath").Value;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName);

    var buffer = new char[4096];
    int numberRead;
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    while ((numberRead = reader.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(buffer[..numberRead]);
    }

    return Ok(stringBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: 1) What does `hugeObject` look like?  Is it an array or collection?  2) What .NET /.NET Core version are you coding against?  3) Why not use `System.Text.Json`, which supports async serialization and deserialization?

Comment: You could use `Utf8JsonWriter` for that purpose, which allows streaming the output JSON on the fly

Comment: @Workj - thanks for including the JSON.  It would also be helpful to know the precise .NET version you are working with.  You tagged this [tag:asp.net-core] but `PushStreamContent` is only built into Asp.NET, not core.  It would be much easier for us to help you if we knew exactly which framework you are using.  Thanks!

Comment: @dbc thanks for your patience. I am using .NET Core 8.0 .I am reviewing the Utf8JsonWriter and I still don't see a way to do it. Let me simplify my request: I want to minimize memory use. So stream the JSON text file in; I don't need to parse it, I Just need to send it as is back out on a response. I would like to stream the response as well.

Comment: What implementation of `PushStreamContent` are you using?

Comment: And also, why use `PushStreamContent`?  Is it only to reduce memory usage, or is it because you really need push instead of pull semantics?  Because, accordinh to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16171977) by Kiran in 2013 to [WebAPI StreamContent vs PushStreamContent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16168683), neither buffer their responses so neither should result in a memory spike.

Comment: In most cases, the right way to build an API that serves a large object like this is to paginate the API (and allow caller to request chunks of data.)

Even if you came up with a clever way to serialize and stream the payload now, assuming the payload grows in future, you'll run into the exact same memory spike again eventually.

Comment: @dbc Since I am new to streaming I am using PushStreamContent because I found several examples that use it. Is there a better way of streaming data in from a file and then streaming the data back out in the response? Note: The data is not going to a front-end, a calling application wants a string of Json data.

Comment: I think maybe you can just use `IAsyncEnumerable`.  What is the signature of your Web API method?

Comment: public HttpResponseMessage GetData()

Comment: Found this: Parsing 90GB JSON Files Using Streams in .NET  https://medium.com/geekculture/parsing-huge-json-files-using-streams-in-net-d620dace47e2 I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge to suggest this as an answer, but I think UTF8JsonReader serves your purpose: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-utf8jsonreader#read-from-a-stream-using-utf8jsonreader:~:text=Fabrikam%20University%22%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D-,Read%20from%20a%20stream%20using%20Utf8JsonReader,-When%20reading%20a

Comment: @WorkJ - do you want to transform the JSON data in any way, or do you just want to return the `fileName` file verbatim without any transformation at all?

Comment: @dbc I want to return  it without any transformation at all. The input file is already a Json text file. I want to read the file in, and send the data back out as a stream to a calling application.

Comment: In that case you shouldn't need to do anything other than do 1) Change your signature to `public async Task<IActionResult>`  and 2) [`return File(stream, "text/json", fileName)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-8.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controllerbase-file(system-io-stream-system-string-system-string)) as shown in [Return file in ASP.Net Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42460443).  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Correction: `"application/json"`.

Comment: You're welcome.  Should I add an answer, or mark as a duplicate?  Or I see that you did.

Comment: You are welcome to add an answer and I will mark  it so you get credit. I will remove my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you simply want to return a file without transforming it in any way, you may do so by returning a [`FileStreamResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filestreamresult) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42460443) by [Nkosi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5233410/nkosi) to *[Return file in ASP.Net Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42460198)*, using the `"application/json"` content type, like so:

```
[HttpGet, Route("/api/GetAllData/{callingApp}")]
public IActionResult GetAllData(
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$"), Required, MaxLength(50)] string callingApp)
{
    var fileName = _config.GetSection("AllAgentsPath").Value;
    Stream stream;
    try
    {
        stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return NotFound(); // returns a NotFoundResult with Status404NotFound response.
    }

    return File(stream, "application/json", fileName);
}
```

The [`ControllerBase.File(Stream, String, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-8.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controllerbase-file(system-io-stream-system-string-system-string)) method returns a [`FileStreamResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filestreamresult) class.  This class

> Represents an ActionResult that when executed will write a file from a stream to the response.

Having done so the framework should return the contents of your file without loading the entire file into memory, then [close the stream when complete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26275764).